# Entity Framework 5 invalid column name?

Tags: mapping, entity-framework-5, fluent

I try to test WPF, C# and EF 5 for developing a desktop application.
When I execute context.SaveChanges, i have the following exception :
Invalid column name simulation_SimulationID. I tried severale tips, but i was unable to solve this problem, everything seems to be correct. below entities:

```
//Entity Echeance
 public partial class Echeance : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public long EheanceId { get; set; }
    public byte EchNumber { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime date { get; set; }
    public Double principal { get; set; }
    public Double interet { get; set; }
    public byte isLoy1 { get; set; }
    public long SimulationId { get; set; }
    public virtual simulation simulation { get; set; }

    //Attributs non mappés
    public Double tva { get; set; }
    public Double txtva { get; set; }
    public Double horstaxe { get; set; }
    public Double ttc { get; set; }
    public Double amtfin { get; set; }
    public Double encfin { get; set; }

    //Constructeur avec numéro de loyer
    public Echeance(byte nnloy)
    {
        EchNumber = nnloy;
        date = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 25);
        principal = 0.000;
        interet = 0.000;
        horstaxe = 0.000;
        tva = 0.000;
        ttc = 0.000;
        isLoy1 = 0;
        ttc = 0.000;
        amtfin = 0.000;
        encfin = 0.000;
    }



    //Constructeur sans paramètres avec valeurs par défaut
    public Echeance()
    {
        EchNumber = 0;
        date = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 25);
        principal = 0.000;
        interet = 0.000;
        horstaxe = 0.000;
        tva = 0.000;
        ttc = 0.000;
        isLoy1 = 0;
        ttc = 0.000;
        amtfin = 0.000;
        encfin = 0.000;
    }



    //Propriété Numloy : numéro loyer
    public byte NumLoy
    {
        get { return EchNumber; }
        set
        {
            EchNumber = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Numloy");
        }
    }

    public DateTime DateEcheance
    {
        get { return date; }
        set
        {
            date = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DateEcheance");
        }

    }

    public Double MontantPrincipal
    {
        get
        {
            return principal;
        }

        set
        {
            principal = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MontantPrincipal");
        }
    }


    public Double MontantInteret
    {
        get
        {
            return interet;
        }

        set
        {
            interet = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("MontantInteret");
        }
    }

    public Double MontantHT
    {
        get
        {
            return horstaxe;
        }

        set
        {
            horstaxe = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MontantHT");
        }
    }


    public Double MontantTVA
    {
        get
        {
            return tva;
        }

        set
        {
            tva = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("MontantTVA");
        }
    }

    public Double MontantTTC
    {
        get
        {
            return ttc;
        }

        set
        {
            ttc = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("MontantTTC");
        }
    }


    public byte FirstLoyer
    {
        get { return isLoy1; }
        set
        {
            isLoy1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstLoyer");
        }
    }

    public Double Encours
    {
        get { return encfin; }
        set
        {
            encfin = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Encours");
        }
    }


    public Double Amortfin
    {
        get { return amtfin; }
        set
        {
            amtfin = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Amortfin");
        }
    }


    public Double TauxTVA
    {
        get { return txtva; }
        set
        {
            txtva = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TauxTVA");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
      {
          PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

          if (handler != null)
              handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

      }

}



//Entity simulation
 public partial class simulation : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

        public long SimulationId { get; set; }
        public Double baseLocative { get; set; }
        public Double txInt { get; set; }
        public Double txVr { get; set; }
        public Double Autofin { get; set; }
        public byte echjour { get; set; }
        public Byte duree { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime echBegin { get; set; }
        public Double loy1 { get; set; }
        public Byte loy1_freq { get; set; }
        public Double encfin { get; set; }
        public Double loyer { get; set; }
        public Double txtva { get; set; }
        public Byte perio { get; set; }
        public Double ratio { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<Echeance> echeancier { get; set; }
        //public virtual ICollection<Echeance> echeancier { get; set; }

        //Non mappés 

        Double Totpri;
        Double Totint;
        Double Totht;
        Double Tottva;
        Double Totttc;
        Double loyDuplicate;
        Double _timbre;


      //Constructeur sans paramètres
        public simulation()
        {
            baseLocative = 0.000;
            txInt = 0.000;
            txVr = 0.000;
            Autofin = 0.000;
            echjour = 25;
            duree = 36;
            loyer = 0.000;
            loy1 = 0.000;
            loy1_freq =1;
            perio = 1;
            txtva = 18.000;
            Totpri = 0.000;
            Totint = 0.000;
            Totht = 0.000;
            Tottva = 0.000;
            Totttc = 0.000;
            loyDuplicate = 0.000;
            _timbre = 0.000;

            int y = DateTime.Today.Year;
            int m = DateTime.Today.Month;
            int djour = DateTime.Today.Day;
            int j = 25;

            if (djour > 25)
            {

                m = m + 1;
                    if (m > 12)
                    {
                        m = 1;
                        y = y + 1;
                    }
            }



            //Date française
            CultureInfo  culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
            DateTimeStyles  styles = DateTimeStyles.None;
            DateTime dd;

            string datestring = j.ToString() + "/" + m.ToString() + "/" + y.ToString();
            DateTime.TryParse(datestring, culture, styles, out dd );
            echBegin = dd;

           echeancier = new List<Echeance>();
        }


        //Constructeur avec  paramètres
        public simulation(Double bl, Double txi, Double txr, Double autofin, Byte jouech, Byte ldur, DateTime ech1, Double loy1mnt, Byte per,Double timbre)
        {
            baseLocative = bl;
            txInt = txi;
            txVr = txr;
            perio = per;
            Autofin = autofin;
            echjour = jouech;
            duree = ldur;
            echBegin = ech1;
            loy1 = loy1mnt;
            loy1_freq = 1;
            encfin = 0.000;
            ratio = 0.000;
            _timbre = timbre;
            echeancier = new List<Echeance>();
        }


        //Propriété base locative
        public Double Montant
        {
            get { return baseLocative; }
            set
            {
                baseLocative = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Montant");
            }

        }

        //Propriété Taux d'intérêts
        public Double Txtint
        {
            get { return txInt; }
            set
            {
                txInt = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Txtint");
            }

        }


        //Propriété Taux valeur résiduelle
        public Double Txtvr
        {
            get { return txVr; }
            set
            {
                txVr = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Txtvr");
            }

        }


        //Propriété Autofinancement
        public Double Autofinancement
        {
            get { return Autofin; }
            set
            {
                Autofin = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Autofinancement");
            }

        }

        //Propriété Jour échéance
        public Byte JourEcheance
        {
            get { return echjour; }
            set
            {
                echjour = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("JourEcheance");
            }

        }

        //Propriété Jour échéance
        public Byte DureeCtr
        {
            get { return duree; }
            set
            {
                duree = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DureeCtr");
            }

        }

        //Propriété Jour échéance
        public DateTime BeginEch
        {
            get { return echBegin; }
            set
            {
                echBegin = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("BeginEch");
            }

        }

        //Propriété Jour échéance
        public Double Loyer
        {
            get { return loyer; }
            set
            {
                loyer = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Loyer");
            }
        }

        //Périodicté
        public Byte Periodicite
        {
            get { return perio; }
            set
            {
                perio = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Periodicite");
            }
        }



        //Premier loyer
        public Double FirstLoyer
        {
            get { return loy1; }
            set
            {
                loy1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FirstLoyer");
            }
        }

        public Double TxtTva
        {
            get { return txtva; }
            set
            {
                txtva = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TxtTva");
            }
        }


        //Nombre de répétition du premier loyer
        public Byte FrequenceLoy1
        {
            get { return loy1_freq; }
            set
            {
                loy1_freq = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FrequenceLoy1");
            }
        }


        public Double TotalPri
        {
            get { return Totpri ; }
            set
            {
                Totpri = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TotalPri");
            }
        }

        public Double TotalInt
        {
            get { return Totint; }
            set
            {
                Totint = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TotalInt");
            }
        }

        public Double TotalHt
        {
            get { return Totht; }
            set
            {
                Totht = value;
               OnPropertyChanged("TotalHt");
            }
        }



        public Double TotalTva
        {
            get { return Tottva; }
            set
            {
                Tottva = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("TotalTva");
            }
        }

        public Double TotalTtc
        {
            get { return Totttc; }
            set
            {
                Totttc = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TotalTtc");
            }
        }


        public Double Encfin
        {
            get { return encfin; }
            set
            {
                encfin = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Encfin");
            }
        }

        public Double Ratio
        {
            get { return ratio; }
            set
            {
                ratio = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Ratio");
            }
        }


        public Double LoyForDuplicate
        {
            get
            {
                return loyDuplicate;
            }
            set
            {
                loyDuplicate = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LoyForDuplicate");
            }
        }


        //public IList<Echeance> ListEcheances
        public IList<Echeance> ListEcheances
        {
            get
            {
                return echeancier;
            }
            set
            {
                echeancier = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ListEcheance");
            }
        }


        public Double Timbre
        {
            get
            {
                return _timbre;
            }
            set
            {
                _timbre = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Timbre");
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
}
```

And My dbContext :

```
 public class MyContext : DbContext
{

    ILogger _currentLog = null;

    public DbSet<simulation> Simulations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Echeance> Echeances { get; set; }


    public MyContext(string cnxString, ILogger logger)
        : base(cnxString)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
        _currentLog = logger;
        if (_currentLog != null)
            _currentLog.LogInfoMessage("Connexion établie.");
    }

    public MyContext(ILogger logger)
        : base("name=dbleaseEntities")
    {
      //  Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
        _currentLog = logger;
        if (_currentLog != null)
             _currentLog.LogInfoMessage("Connexion établie.");
    }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        _currentLog.LogInfoMessage("Mapping en cours...");
        try
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SimulationMapping());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EcheanceMapping());

            //************************************************************************************************************************
            //Propriétés non mappées (à ignorer) pour l'entité simulation 
            //Autofinancement JourEcheance DureeCtr BeginEch Loyer Periodicite FirstLoyer TxtTva FrequenceLoy1 LoyForDuplicate Timbre
            //Les propriétés à ignorer lors de mapping
            //************************************************************************************************************************
            _currentLog.LogInfoMessage("Ignorer les champs de l'entité simulation.");
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.TotalPri);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.TotalInt);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.TotalHt);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.TotalTva);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.TotalTtc);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.Montant);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.Txtint);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.Txtvr);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.Autofinancement);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.JourEcheance);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.DureeCtr);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.BeginEch);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.Loyer);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.Periodicite);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.FirstLoyer);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.TxtTva);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.FrequenceLoy1);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.LoyForDuplicate);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.Ratio);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.Timbre);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.Encfin);

            //************************************************************************************************************************
            //Propriétés non mappées (à ignorer) pour l'entité Echeance 
            //NumLoy, DateEcheance, MontantPrincipal, MontantInteret, MontantHT, MontantTVA, MontantTTC, FirstLoyer, Encours, Amortfin, TauxTVA
            //tva, txtva,horstaxe, ttc, amtfin, encfin 
            //************************************************************************************************************************
            _currentLog.LogInfoMessage("Ignorer les champs de l'entité Echéance.");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.NumLoy);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.DateEcheance);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.MontantPrincipal);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.MontantInteret);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.MontantHT);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.MontantTVA);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.MontantTTC);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.FirstLoyer);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.Encours);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.Amortfin);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.TauxTVA);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.tva);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.txtva);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.horstaxe);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.ttc);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.amtfin);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.encfin);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            _currentLog.LogInfoMessage("Mapping terminée avec succès.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _currentLog.LogException(ex);
            throw ex;

        }

    }
```

Mapping with Fluent Code :

```
public class EcheanceMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Echeance>
{
    public EcheanceMapping()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.EheanceId);
        this.ToTable("Echeance");
        this.Property(t => t.EheanceId).HasColumnName("EheanceId").IsRequired()
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        this.Property(t => t.EchNumber).HasColumnName("EchNumber").IsRequired();
        this.Property(t => t.date).HasColumnName("date").IsRequired();
        this.Property(t => t.principal).HasColumnName("principal");
        this.Property(t => t.interet).HasColumnName("interet");
        this.Property(t => t.isLoy1).HasColumnName("isloy1").IsRequired();
        this.Property(t => t.SimulationId).HasColumnName("simulationId").IsRequired();
        this.HasRequired(t => t.simulation).WithMany(t => t.echeancier).HasForeignKey(d => new { d.SimulationId });



    }
}

 public class SimulationMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<simulation>
{
 public SimulationMapping()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.SimulationId);
        this.ToTable("simulation");
        this.Property(t => t.SimulationId)
            .HasColumnName("SimulationId")
            .IsRequired()
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            //.HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(new Nullable<DatabaseGeneratedOption>(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity));

        this.Property(t => t.baseLocative).HasColumnName("Baselocative").IsRequired();
        this.Property(t => t.txInt).HasColumnName("txInt").IsRequired();

           this.Property(t => t.txVr).HasColumnName("txvr");
           this.Property(t => t.Autofin).HasColumnName("Autofin");
           this.Property(t => t.echjour).HasColumnName("echjour").IsRequired();
           this.Property(t => t.duree).HasColumnName("duree").IsRequired();
           this.Property(t => t.echBegin).HasColumnName("echBegin").IsRequired();
           this.Property(t => t.loy1).HasColumnName("loy1");
           this.Property(t => t.loy1_freq).HasColumnName("loy1_freq");
           this.Property(t => t.encfin).HasColumnName("encfin");
           this.Property(t => t.loyer).HasColumnName("loyer");
           this.Property(t => t.txtva).HasColumnName("txtva");
           this.Property(t => t.perio).HasColumnName("perio").IsRequired();
           this.Property(t => t.ratio).HasColumnName("ratio");
    }
}
```

I use the following Unit Of Work :

```
 public class UnitOfWork : MyContext, IUnitOfWork, IQueryableUnitOfWork
{

    private ILogger _logger;
    public UnitOfWork(string cnxString, ILogger logger) : base(cnxString, logger)
    {

    }

    public UnitOfWork(ILogger logger)
        : base(logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }


    //Marquer une entitié de type <T> comme nouveau dans le contexte
    public void RegisterNew<T>(T item) where T : class
    {
        _logger.LogInfoMessage("Marquage d'une entitié [" + item.GetType().Name + "] comme nouveau.");
        try
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                base.Entry<T>(item).State = EntityState.Added;
                _logger.LogInfoMessage("Marquage d'une entitié [" + item.GetType().Name + "] comme nouveau.");
            }
            else
                _logger.LogInfoMessage("Entité nulle lors de marquage comme nouveau.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogException(ex);
            throw ex;
        }

    }


    //Marquer une entitié de type <T> comme modifiée dans le contexte
    public void RegisterChanged<T>(T item) where T : class
    {

        base.Entry<T>(item).State = EntityState.Modified;

    }


    //Marquer une entitié de type <T> comme unchangé dans le contexte
    public void RegisterUnChanged<T>(T item) where T : class
    {
        base.Entry<T>(item).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

    }


    //Marquer une entitié de type <T> comme supprimée dans le contexte
    public void RegisterDeleted<T>(T item) where T : class
    {
        base.Entry<T>(item).State = EntityState.Deleted;

    }


    //Récupère du contexte le dbset du type <T>
    public IDbSet<T> GetSet<T>() where T : class
    {

        return base.Set<T>();
    }



    public IQueryable<T> GetQueryableSet<T>() where T : class
    {
         return base.Set<T>();

    }



    public void Rollback()
    {
        base.ChangeTracker.Entries().ToList().ForEach(e => e.State = EntityState.Unchanged);
    }



    public void Commit()
    {
        try
        {
            base.SaveChanges();
        }

        catch (DbUpdateException e)
        {
            var innerEx = e.InnerException;
            while (innerEx.InnerException != null)
                innerEx = innerEx.InnerException;
            throw new Exception(innerEx.Message);
        }

        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var entry in e.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var error in entry.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}",
                    entry.Entry.Entity,
                    error.PropertyName,
                    error.ErrorMessage
                ));
                }
            }
            throw new Exception(sb.ToString());
        }
    }


    public void Attach<T>(T item) where T : class
    {
        base.Entry<T>(item).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it is a One-to-many Relationship : one "simulation" must correspond to one or n "Echeance", and "Echeance" cannot exist without simulation. SimulationId Is a primary key in table "simulation" and a foreing key in table "echeance" and it is an  identity column (sql server 2008).
I used IList instead of ICollection, because i want to edit list of "echeance" in WPF datagrid, it is impossible with ICollection.

Now When i execute uow.Commit() i get "Invalid colmun name simulation_SimulationID".

Your help would be welcome...Thanks.

Comment: That's a lot of code to expect someone on the internet to dig through. It might be worthwhile to reduce your code to the minimum required to reproduce the problem and post that instead. Doing this might also help you identify where the problem is :)

Comment: I thought that to send the maximum of code can help to detect the problem. So the reader can have a global view Because I don't know where the problem can be located : in POCO or in Mapping or in the context ??? these notions are new for me.

Comment: The error is in regards to a single property of a single entity, and much of the other code could be removed. It's something to try, to help isolate your problem.